# How to display the records but show the value as 0 in the result if the condition is not true SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
    TA.MOBILE_NUMBER, 
    TA.AMOUNT, 
    TA.REFERENCEID, 
    TB.KEYCOST 
FROM TABLEA TA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB TB ON TA.REFERENCEID = TB.REFERENCEID
WHERE TA.STATUS = 0
  AND TB.ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'
```

Some `referenceid's tableA` have an entry with `ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'` in `tableb` but some `referenceid's` doesn't have any entry with `ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'`.

I want to display all the `referenceid's` from `tableA` with the `KEYCOST` they have in `TableB`. If a `referenceid` in `TableA` doesn't have any `KEYCOST`, then the result should have that data but display 0 in the `KEYCOST` column.

Please if someone could help me here. 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the join condition to ON statement, as for NULL values simple NVL should help, it will show the second value if the first one is null. Like this:

```
SELECT TA.MOBILE_NUMBER, TA.AMOUNT, TA.REFERENCEID, NVL(TB.KEYCOST,0) KEYCOST FROM TABLEA TA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB TB
ON TA.REFERENCEID = TB.REFERENCEID AND TB.ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'
WHERE TA.STATUS = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *second* table need to go into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT TA.MOBILE_NUMBER, TA.AMOUNT, TA.REFERENCEID, TB.KEYCOST
FROM TABLEA TA LEFT JOIN 
     TABLEB TB
     ON TA.REFERENCEID = TB.REFERENCEID AND TB.ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'
WHERE TA.STATUS = 0;
```

Otherwise, the `NULL` values produced by the `LEFT JOIN` get filtered out.

If you need to get `0` instead of `NULL`, then use `COALESCE()`.  It is not clear which column you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. this is the output i was expecting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to display all the `referenceid's` from `tableA` with the `KEYCOST` they have in `TableB`. If a `referenceid` in `TableA` doesn't have any `KEYCOST`, then the result should have that data but display `0` in the `KEYCOST` column.

```
SELECT 
    TA.MOBILE_NUMBER, 
    TA.AMOUNT, 
    TA.REFERENCEID, 
    NVL(TB.KEYCOST, 0) KEYCOST 
FROM TABLEA TA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB TB ON TA.REFERENCEID = TB.REFERENCEID
    AND TB.ALIAS = TA.ALIAS
WHERE TA.STATUS = 0
  AND TA.ALIAS = 'KEYCOST'
```

According to you explanation, you want to `SELECT` data with `ALIAS` = `KEYCOST` so we have to keep condition for `tableA` also and add `AND` in `join` with `ALIAS` column.